# Python: Daemon vs. Infinity cycle

Tags: python, unix, daemon

I have a question: What's the difference between [this](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) method of creating a python-daemon script and this:

```
while(True):
   do_something()
   sleep(10)
```

Comment: [correct daemon behavior](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a process, being a daemon means much more than just containing an infinite loop. It should not terminate when its parent process (usually shell) is terminated. It should support an interface for stopping, starting and restarting (when its program file is executed with start|stop|restart parameter). That's what the example you mentioned does.

P.S. My list of things a daemon should do is not complete, it just shows there are such things.

Comment: Daemon program usually support some system signals to do restart/stop/start. The parameters are usually used in scripts in /etc/init.d/ to send these signal to correct process id (pid). But now, daemons will be probably less popular becasue `systemd` is around and it does good job handling processes properly, so it is not necessary to do magic tricks like double fork (it makes daemon to run in background).

Comment: @spinus, true about signals. As for systemd, I'm still not familiar with it, as the distribution I prefer doesn't use it. Anyway, good news that double fork will be unnecessary someday. :-)

Comment: @Ellioh: there is a temporary solution. Systemd can work as user process so you can manage only the process of specific user/class and not integrating it with the rest of the system (but for me it not work correctly yet, they are implementing this now). There is supervisord program which I use to deploy things (it is something like poor systemd for user processes) - so I use initd for old deamons and for non-forking programs I use supervisord (there is also circus but for me supervisord fits better). Give it a try.